# GatsbyJS How to use GraphQL to fetch markdown files and display data on specific page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm building a `gatsby`-site where I want to display some `markdown`-files on specific pages by using `graphql`.

my structure is like this:

```
src
  content
     about
       file1.md
       file2.md
     services
       somefile.md
       another.md
  pages
     about
       index.js

// etc.
```

an example of a markdown-file is:

```
---
key: about
title: some title
---
## this is some section header

this is some dummy text
```

then I have my react file e.g. for example the about page, where I want to display all the `markdown`-files which are located in the `content/about`-folder..

```
import React from "react"

const AboutPage = ({data}) => {

   return(
       <div>
        // here the markdown data should be displayed
      </div>
   ) 
}
```

Can I do a `graphql`-query specific for this page only? Could I fetch the data by querying the key or should I set a path value?

Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/docs/docs/adding-markdown-pages.md

Comment: @LivingThing thanks for the tip! :-) Hmm but should I then give every markdown file inside my about folder the attribute `path: '/about'` ??

Comment: I think that the path should be unique. Name it according to what information the page is suppose to display

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby-source-filesystem plugin will allow you to get files within a directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already resolved this but I came across something similar. You can add a filter to the frontmatter:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark(
    filter: {
      frontmatter: {
        title: { eq:"Intro" }
      }
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        fileAbsolutePath
        id
        frontmatter {
          title
          path
          date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
          imgSrc
        }
        html
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:
[Result from GraphiQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2kSk.png)

Hope that helps.